# How to mirror iPhone on other device running on Windows or Android

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to mirror an iPhone on Windows or Android? I know that there's an app called iTools that has the function to mirror an iPhone even on windows. I guess that it requires to run Bonjour service in order for the phone discover the device just like an Apple TV. So, I am thinking that maybe I can take the display of the phone by a series of screenshots and send them as video frames via airplay to that device, and that device will just decode it and show the frames on its screen. And I making sense? or are there any other ways? I just need some ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 9 it is no longer possible to take screenshots of the entire iPhone screen. Apple locked that down. An app can capture it's views, but you can't capture stuff that your app does not draw, or capture the screen when you're in the background.

The only way I know of to do this now is AirPlay. There are a couple of apps that make a Mac or PC act like an AppleTV and let you display your screen to them using mirroring. I believe they had to reverse-engineer the AirPlay protocol in order to do that, although I remember reading about an AirPlay API added in iOS 9.

Comment: Sorry, can't upvote you. Thank you for the quick response. Just an additional question, do you think that devices running Android could also support airplay and act like an Apple TV?

Comment: I doubt it, since AirPlay is an Apple-specific technology. I guess it's possible, but you'd have to do a BUNCH of work to simulate the protocols involved.